# Memoizing function with condition?

Tags: haskell, memoization

Trying to extend memoizing fibonacci function for negative arguments.
Bellow is a code which obvioulsy works with positive values only:

```
fib :: Integer -> Integer
fib = (map fib' [0..] !!) . fromInteger
    where
    fib' 0        = 0
    fib' 1        = 1
    fib' n        = (fib $ n-2) + (fib $ n-1)
    negfib' 0     = 1
    negfib' 1     = -1
    negfib' n     = (fib $ n+2) - (fib $ n+1)
```

How can I alter `fib` definition so it would also cache results with `negfib'` when called with a negative number ?

Attempted with pattern guards

```
fib n
    | n>= 0     = (map fib' [0..] !!) . fromInteger $ n
    | otherwise = (map negfib' [0..] !!) . fromInteger $ -n - 1
```

or enclosed in lambda function

```
fib = (\n -> if n >= 0
                 then map fib' [0..] !!) . fromInteger $ n
                 else map negfib' [0..] !!) . fromInteger $ -n - 1
```

which did not helped, as lists of partially applied fibonnaci function thunks is not pre-generated this way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're very close!

Just pull the map statements out further:

```
fib = lookup
  where fibs = map fib' [0..]
        negfibs = map negfib' [0..]
        lookup n | n >= 0    = (fibs !!) . fromInteger $ n
                 | otherwise = (negfibs !!) . fromInteger $ -n - 1
```

Now the definition of `fibs` and `negfibs` only happens once (with the definition of `fib`) as opposed for each `n`.

Comment: Oh, thank you. If I can understand it right, the whole point is to separate functions which do the calculation to force them pre-generate list of partial results. Can be the same achieved anyhow with forced strictness like with `seq` ?

Comment: it's more a question of scope than strictness. When `fib = \n -> let fibs = map fib' [0..] in fibs !! n` returns, `fibs` drops out of scope, and is forgotten. When `fib = let fibs = map fib' [0..] in \n -> fibs !! n` returns, fibs is still in scope (to `fib`, not to the rest of the file).